# Quiero validar la ingresion de codigos repetidos en una base de datos pero no funciona mi codigo

Tags: java, base-de-datos, netbeans, validación

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un punto de venta programado en netbeans, tengo la interfaz y esta conformada por varios modulos, uno de ellos es el modulo "Inventario" en el cual puedes agregar, modificar, eliminar o buscar articulos de la base de datos.

El problema es el siguiente, quiero que cuando ingreses un codigo que ya esta en uso en la base de datos te mande un mensaje de error y no te lo registre en esta, para eso hice el siguiente metodo al presionar el boton "Agregar" del inventario, el cual llama primero a un metodo llamado "existeCodigo" que se encuentra en otra clase llamada "ArticuloDAO", el metodo de "existeCodigo" se supone que busca el codigo en la base de datos y verifica si ya se uso, todo el codigo parece correcto hasta el momento, el problema es que no esta funcionando, me sigue dejando agregar articulos con codigos que ya existen y no se por que.. Ya le pregunte a una IA y me dijo que el codigo parece estar en orden, asi que ahora recurro a ustedes para que me ayuden a solucionarlo..

El codigo de el metodo del boton "Agregar" es el siguiente:

```
private void btnGuardarProductoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
try {
    if (artiDAO.existeCodigo(arti)) {
        System.out.println("El código ya existe en la base de datos. No se puede insertar el artículo.");
        return; // Salir del método si el código ya existe
    }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Error al consultar la existencia del código: " + e.getMessage());
}
    if (!"".equals(txtCodigo.getText()) || !"".equals(txtDescripcion.getSelectedItem()) || !"".equals(txtCantidad.getText()) || !"".equals(txtPrecio.getText()) || !"".equals(txtNombreArti.getText())) {
        arti.setCodigo(txtCodigo.getText());
        arti.setNombre_articulo(txtNombreArti.getText());
        arti.setDescripcion(txtDescripcion.getSelectedItem().toString());
        arti.setCantidad(Integer.parseInt(txtCantidad.getText()));
        arti.setPrecio(Float.parseFloat(txtPrecio.getText()));
        artiDAO.RegistrarArticulo(arti);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto Registrado.");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los campos están vacíos.");
    }
```

}

El codigo del metodo "existeCodigo" es el siguiente:

```
public boolean existeCodigo(Articulo arti) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articulo WHERE codigo = ?";
    try{
    con = cn.getConnection();
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1,arti.getCodigo());
    //PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
    resultSet.next();
    int count = resultSet.getInt(1);
    return count > 0;
    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Añado tambien el codigo de la clase "Articulo" que es la que guarda los datos de los articulos en sets y gets, por eso utilizo un objeto de la clase "Articulo" al llamar al metodo, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
package Modelo;
```

//Constructor para varibles del Articulo con getters y seters

```
public class Articulo {
   private int id_articulo;
   private float precio;
   private String descripcion;
   private int cantidad;
   private String nombre_articulo;
   private String codigo;

public Articulo(){
    
}

public Articulo(int id_articulo, float precio, String descripcion, int cantidad, String nombre_articulo, String codigo) {
    this.id_articulo = id_articulo;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
    this.nombre_articulo = nombre_articulo;
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public int getId_articulo() {
    return id_articulo;
}

public void setId_articulo(int id_articulo) {
    this.id_articulo = id_articulo;
}

public float getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(float precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public String getNombre_articulo() {
    return nombre_articulo;
}

public void setNombre_articulo(String nombre_articulo) {
    this.nombre_articulo = nombre_articulo;
}

public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
```

}

Alguna idea de por que no esta funcionando?, el sistema esta conectado correctamente a la base de datos y si te registra todo, el problema es solo que quiero que no se puedan repetir los codigos entre articulos.. Si necesitan algun otro metodo o clase para revisar solo comentenme y se los comparto..

Muchas Gracias!

Comment: El problema lo tienes en el diseño de la tabla. Si tratas de manejar las restricciones (`CONSTRAINTS`) desde el código de la aplicación, a la larga se vuelve inmanejable porque cuan más grande se hace la base de datos, de más cosas tendrás que estar atento, y al final terminas con errores e inconsistencias por todas partes. Debes hacer que el `id` sea la `PRIMARY KEY` de la tabla, o bien, al menos haz que sea un campo `UNIQUE`, así cuando intentes agregar un código que ya existe, la propia base de datos se "quejará". Si puedes también haz que el campo sea `AUTO INCREMENT`.

Comment: Para ser un poco más explícito. Yo cambiaría el `id` de la tabla y usaría `codigo` como `PRIMARY KEY`. Y si lo puedo hacer `AUTO INCREMENT` sería mucho mejor a menos que tenga que tener uno específico. Pero si lo tienes que tener separado, entonces haz que el campo `codigo` sea `UNIQUE` y maneja el error, que te lanzará la base de datos, con un `try {...} catch{...}` cuando detecte que el código ya está en uso.